# How to mock ServletContext getResource?

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, mocking

i am currently writing Junit-Tests for on OData-Application (a hobby project). In there, I initialize a Servlet with the init() function. In order to receive specific application settings, i use the context.getResource() method.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    try {
        super.init(config);
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        URL resourceUrl = context.getResource("/WEB-INF/config.properties");
        if (resourceUrl == null) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Unable to find config.properties");
        }
        Path configFile = Paths.get(resourceUrl.toURI());
```

Now, I try to mock it. The Servlet itself is easy to mock, but im getting error when i try to mock the "getResource"-functionality. Here is my Junit-(beforeClass) Block:

```
public static ODataServlet getServlet() throws MalformedURLException {
    if (servlet == null) {
        servletConfig = new MockServletConfig(); 
        MockServletContext context = new MockServletContext();
        Path path = Paths.get("src/test/resources/config.properties");
        when(context.getResource("/WEB-INF/config.properties")).thenReturn(path.toUri().toURL());

        servlet = new ODataServlet(){
             /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public ServletContext getServletContext() {
                  return context; // return the mock
                }
        };
        servlet.init(servletConfig);
    }
    return servlet;
}
```

Unfortunately, i always get the Exception:

*org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.*

In the line

`when(context.getResource("/WEB-INF/config.properties")).thenReturn(path.toUri().toURL());`

I dont understand why. the context-Object **is** a MockedObject (MockServletContext).

Any advice ? Im also thinking changing everytghing to classloader.getResource as a workaround. But actually i like it like this ...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sephir

**UPDATE:**  **SOLVED**. After literally only a few minutes in here, some guys pointed out the Issue: MockServletContext context is from the Package org.springframework.mock.web which is not working with the Mockito.

After changing the MockServletContext

```
   MockServletContext context = new MockServletContext();
```

to

```
context = Mockito.mock(ServletContext.class);
```

everything is working.

Big thanks to you Guys (!).

Comment: A mocked object is one created with `Mockito.mock(ServletContext.class)`, not your own mock implementation of `ServletContext`.

Comment: Yes (Hi!), MockServletContext is *not* (mockito)Mock!!

Comment: Thanks for the extreme fast reply. Yes, obvious after the solution :) Its working now! Thanks very much @tgdavis and xerx593.